# Array of object creation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one array of the object which is looked like below.

I have applied some of the logic here but don't know what is problem here.

```js
let inputObj = [
 {
  user_category_id: '1',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '1',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 1' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '2',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '2',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 2' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '3',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '3',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 3' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '4',
  category_id: '2',
  subcategory_id: '4',
  category_name: 'Category 2',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 4' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '5',
  category_id: '2',
  subcategory_id: '5',
  category_name: 'Category 2',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 5' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '6',
  category_id: '3',
  subcategory_id: '6',
  category_name: 'Category 3',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 6' 
 },
]

let tempUserSubcategory = []
inputObj.forEach((val, index) => {
  tempUserSubcategory[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`] = [`${val.subcategory_id}:${val.subcategory_name}`]
});

console.log(tempUserSubcategory)
```

My expected output:

```
let outputObj = {
    '1:Category 1' : [
        '1:Sub Category 1',
        '2:Sub Category 2',
        '3:Sub Category 3'
    ],
    '2:Category 2' : [
        '4:Sub Category 4',
        '5:Sub Category 5'
    ],
    '3:Category 3' : [
        '6:Sub Category 6'
    ],
}
```

Kindly check my fiddle here.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o7x5fn0m/2/)

Thank you so much.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax of your expected output is invalid. Objects need `{` delimiters, not `[` - `[` indicates an *array*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the wanted key and value keys and get athe key and value from it for creating a property and pushing the value to the result set.

```js
var data = [{ user_category_id: '1', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '1', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 1' }, { user_category_id: '2', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '2', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 2' }, { user_category_id: '3', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '3', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 3' }, { user_category_id: '4', category_id: '2', subcategory_id: '4', category_name: 'Category 2', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 4' }, { user_category_id: '5', category_id: '2', subcategory_id: '5', category_name: 'Category 2', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 5' }, { user_category_id: '6', category_id: '3', subcategory_id: '6', category_name: 'Category 3', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 6' }],
    keys = [['category_id', 'category_name'], ['subcategory_id', 'subcategory_name']],
    result = data.reduce((r, o) => {
        var [key, value] = keys.map(a => a.map(k => o[k]).join(':'));
        (r[key] = r[key] || []).push(value);
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

While this can be accomplished using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in another way, you were pretty close to achieving it. You only need to check if the sub-array you're creating exists, before overriding it. If the array exists, you should push instead of creating another one.

Your line -

```
temp[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`] =  [`${val.subcategory_id}:${val.subcategory_name}`];
```

overrides the array with the last received value and creates another array instead of pushing to the existing one.

Run the snippet below to check -

```js
let inputObj = [
 {
  user_category_id: '1',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '1',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 1' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '2',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '2',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 2' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '3',
  category_id: '1',
  subcategory_id: '3',
  category_name: 'Category 1',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 3' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '4',
  category_id: '2',
  subcategory_id: '4',
  category_name: 'Category 2',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 4' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '5',
  category_id: '2',
  subcategory_id: '5',
  category_name: 'Category 2',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 5' 
 },
 {
  user_category_id: '6',
  category_id: '3',
  subcategory_id: '6',
  category_name: 'Category 3',
  subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 6' 
 },
];

let temp = []
inputObj.forEach((val, index) => {
  if(typeof (temp[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`]) === 'undefined'){
  temp[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`] =  [`${val.subcategory_id}:${val.subcategory_name}`];
  }else{
  temp[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`].push(`${val.subcategory_id}:${val.subcategory_name}`);
  }
});

console.log(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting a wrong output.
Instead you should expect:

```
let outputObj = {
    '1:Category 1' : [
        '1:Sub Category 1',
        '2:Sub Category 2',
        '3:Sub Category 3'
    ],
    '2:Category 2' : [
        '4:Sub Category 4',
        '5:Sub Category 5'
    ],
    '3:Category 3' : [
        '6:Sub Category 6'
    ],
}
```

Here you will have `key` and `value` inside an object.

I have never seen the data structure which you are expecting.

**Solution:**

```js
let inputObj = [{ user_category_id: '1', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '1', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 1'  },  { user_category_id: '2', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '2', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 2'  },  { user_category_id: '3', category_id: '1', subcategory_id: '3', category_name: 'Category 1', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 3'  },  { user_category_id: '4', category_id: '2', subcategory_id: '4', category_name: 'Category 2', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 4'  },  { user_category_id: '5', category_id: '2', subcategory_id: '5', category_name: 'Category 2', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 5'  },  { user_category_id: '6', category_id: '3', subcategory_id: '6', category_name: 'Category 3', subcategory_name: 'Sub Category 6'  }];

let tempUserSubcategory = {};
inputObj.forEach((val, index) => {
  tempUserSubcategory[`${val.category_id}:${val.category_name}`] = [`${val.subcategory_id}:${val.subcategory_name}`];
});

console.log(tempUserSubcategory );
```

Use the above code to get the correct output.

I hope it will help.

Comment: yes. sorry for the mistake. I need this output only.